# Variavel dentro de uma array não funciona

Tags: php, array, variáveis

é um sistema de upload de imagem da CLOUDINARY.

Quando eu uso atribuo um valor fixo para o PUBLIC_ID, funciona!

```
$files["remote"] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($sample_paths["couple"],
array_merge($default_upload_options, array(
  "public_id" => '8273',
))
```

Porém, quando eu eu uso uma variavel para o PUBLIC_ID, o resultado do PUBLIC_ID simplesmente da NULL

```
$files["remote"] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($sample_paths["couple"],
array_merge($default_upload_options, array(
  "public_id" => "$idbusca",
))
```

Oque pode ser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amigo primeiramente em

```
$files["remote"] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($sample_paths["couple"],
array_merge($default_upload_options, array(
  "public_id" => "$idbusca",
))
```

Remova as aspas dupla (**"**) em volta da variável `$idbusca`.

Após isso verifique se realmente essa variável não esta vazia/nula pode ser dessa forma

```
echo 'Var $idbusca:<br/><pre>';
var_dump($idbusca);
echo '</pre>';

$files["remote"] = \Cloudinary\Uploader::upload($sample_paths["couple"],
array_merge($default_upload_options, array(
  "public_id" => $idbusca,
))
```

Pois da forma como está ai ela deveria retornar o valor corretamente. Caso ela realmente esteja vazia o ideal é percorrer o código verificando até onde ela tem a informação e onde ela "perdeu".

Comment: cara, realmente o resultado do var_dump($idbusca) foi NULL, mas a mesma variavel é usada ANTES e DEPOIS e ele tem realmente um valor...

Por favor, Voce tem skype?

Comment: Amigo, RESOLVIDO... O codigo acima estava dentro do:

function do_uploads() {
  global $files, $sample_paths, $default_upload_options, $eager_params;

eu inclui o $idbusca entre essas variaveis, e ficou assim:

function do_uploads() {
  global $files, $sample_paths, $default_upload_options, $eager_params, $idbusca;

MUITO OBRIGADO

Comment: Certo, fico feliz em saber que conseguiu resolver. Não esqueça de validar positivamente minhas respostas caso tenha lhe ajudado. Meus dados de contato estão no meu site https://mfmello.com